# Character encoding issue(broken characters) while getting screenshots on test automation

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, capybara

We have an automation project which is developed with selenium webdriver and ruby(capybara).
We collect screenshots when test case fails. Screenshots are totally fine when we run cases on our local machines. But when we run them on remote machine, we are facing with an character encoding problem on the screenshots. 
Do you have any idea to fix this problem?

Sample screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Chromedriver version: `2.38.552522`

Chrome version: `Google Chrome 66.0.3359.139`

Remote machine:

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

Driver configuration:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :headless_chrome
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome   
  Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
  end    
  Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    options.add_argument 'headless'
    options.add_argument 'disable-gpu'
    options.add_argument 'disable-popup-blocking'
    options.add_argument 'no-sandbox'
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, browser: :chrome, options: options
  end
```

Collect screenshot:

```
page.save_screenshot('testResults/report_smoke_mobile/screenshot_'+scenario.name+'.png')
```

Comment: Does `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` and maybe `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` on remote help?

Comment: Is the site using a font that isn't available on the remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

installing liberation fonts to docker image fixed the problem

```
yum -y install liberation-*
```

Answer (score 0):

Install fonts on your docker image. This works for me!

```
yum groupinstall -y Fonts
```